# How to clear last line in terminal with Golang

Tags: linux, go, terminal

I'm building CLI app (on Linux) where user has to choose something and then I have to clear last line.

I tried several things:

```
  fmt.Print("\r")
  fmt.Print("\033[1")
```

And the cursor goes back to beginning of line, but do not clear the text from the last line.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it that way

```
fmt.Printf("\033[1A\033[K")
```

`\033[1A` - one line up

`\033[K` - delete the line

For example

```
fmt.Println("hello")
fmt.Println("world")
fmt.Printf("\033[1A\033[K")
```

will output only `hello` as the world will be deleted

You can read more about ascii escaping here https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html